# Does scala suport JSR-303 validation?

Tags: scala, bean-validation

Does scala supports JSR-303 validation?

**If it does** - could you please write an example?

**If it does not** - are there workarounds to run JSR-303 validation on scala classes?

Comment: I've found [Accord](https://github.com/wix/accord) open-source library for validation.

Answer (score 7):

There is good news and bad news.

The good news is that you can use JSR-303 annotations in your Scala code with no problems.

Here is an example from a previous project of mine, where all of the annotations are JSR-303 annotations, some of them out of the box, some of them custom.

```
@MessagesValid
class Messages {
  @NotEmpty @Valid
  private var msgs: java.util.List[DeliveredMessage] = _  
  def messages = msgs.asScala

  @ChannelValid 
  var channel: String = _

  var emailFrom: String = _
  var emailReplyTo: String = _

  @PublishAtValid
  var publishAt: String = _
}
```

Note how the `msgs` collection is a `java.util.List`. It needs to be a Java collection for the `@NotEmpty` and `@Valid` to work. But it's easy enough to expose that field as a Scala collection using `JavaConverters`.

The bad news is that you cannot create a JSR-303 annotation using Scala.  You must write those annotations using Java.  So you will need to have a mixed Scala/Java project if you want to write custom JSR-303 annotations.

[There is an old bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-32) (bug #32!) in the Scala bug tracker to support these types of annotations but it is currently closed as Won't Fix.  Please vote for it anyway.

Comment: I wrote custom Constraint annotation in Java and ConstraintValidator in scala, but when I specify `@Constraint(validatedBy = ScalaCustomerValidator.class)` It gives compile error that `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<ScalaCustomerValidator> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>[]`. My ScalaCustomerValidator does extends ConstraintValidator

Comment: @sourcedelica could you please provide the dependencies needed in order to use such annotations?

Comment: https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/jar

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

However, custom annotations are needed for Scala types, as well as custom handling of collections.

If there is any interest, I'll opensource my implementation.