# JSR 303 ConstraintValidator in scala with spring mvc

Tags: java, scala, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have mixed scala-java spring-boot mvc project. I am trying to implement custom validator for request bean using `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator`
I read here and other threads that its better to write annotation in Java [Does scala suport JSR-303 validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284592/does-scala-suport-jsr-303-validation)

I wrote custom Constraint annotation in Java and ConstraintValidator class in scala, but when I specify @Constraint(validatedBy = ScalaCustomerValidator.class) It gives compile error that `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<ScalaCustomerValidator> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>[]`. My ScalaCustomerValidator does extends ConstraintValidator.

//java

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ScalaCustomerValidator.class) //Type mismatch error 
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ScalaCustomerValid {
    String message() default "Invalid tab to filter combination";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

//scala definition of  ConstraintValidator

```
class ScalaCustomerValidator extends ConstraintValidator[ScalaCustomerValid, ScalaCustomer] { .. }
```

javap output:

```
javap ScalaCustomerValidator
Warning: Binary file ScalaCustomerValidator contains com.ScalaCustomerValidator
Compiled from "ScalaCustomerValidator.scala"
public class com.ScalaCustomerValidator implements javax.validation.ConstraintValidator<com.ScalaCustomerValid, com.ScalaCustomer> {
  public void initialize(com.ScalaCustomerValid);
  public boolean isValid(com.ScalaCustomer, javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext);
  public boolean isValid(java.lang.Object, javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext);
  public void initialize(java.lang.annotation.Annotation);
  public com.ScalaCustomerValidator();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by impossibility of getting class of scala object. Scala compiler generates class named ScalaCustomerValidator$ for object ScalaCustomerValidator. ScalaCustomerValidator$ actually implements ConstraintValidator and there is no way to reference it's class. 
If you try in scala:

```
val cl = classOf[ScalaCustomerValidator]
```

you'll get the compile error as well.

This problem is still open: https://issues.scala-lang.org/i#browse/SI-2453

Comment: even after I convert ScalaCustomerValidator to class I get same 'Type Mismatch' error. I Edited my question.

Comment: looks like there is no way for Java annotation's argument to reference scala class type properly. it is referencing it but not realizing that reference is in fact implementing ConstraintValidator.

Comment: I believe there is a way. You can try to decompile your ScalaCustomerValidator.class file, maybe this gives you the hint

Comment: Can you share your decompiled ScalaCustomerValidator.class?

Comment: javap output ok? I paste it in OP. I don't see any hint from there. It looks like expected java source code. ANy other tool I can try?